# Setting frame options for a frame at runtime

Tags: beamer, optional-arguments

I am designing a custom theme. What I want to achieve is I want to construct an if statement that take cares of options of the frame. For an examples you can see the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
    \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{1}{%
          % First frame
          %Set first frame options to [plain,t]
     }{%
          \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{\inserttotalframenumber}{
                  % Last frame
                  %Set last frame options to [plain,c]
          }{%
                 % Other frames
                 %set other frame options to [t]
           }%
      }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
     Top aligned
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Second Frame}
      Top aligned.
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Last Frame}
     Center aligned

  \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Can someone tell me if it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does not set the frame option to `plain` etc. but executes the command, which would be triggered from this option. As it is run before the frame, the frame numbers have to be test for `0` and `\totalframenumber-1`.

I added a random theme to recognise if the `plain` option worked.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
    \ifnum\insertframenumber=0%
        %plain
        \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}%
        \def\beamer@exitcode{\vspace*{-\footheight}\thispagestyle{empty}}%
        %top
        \beamer@centeredfalse%
    \else%
    \ifnum\insertframenumber=\numexpr\inserttotalframenumber-1\relax%
            %plain
            \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}%
            \def\beamer@exitcode{\vspace*{-\footheight}\thispagestyle{empty}}%
            %center
            \beamer@centeredtrue%
    \else%      
            %top
            \beamer@centeredfalse%      
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
     Top aligned
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Second Frame}
      Top aligned.
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Last Frame}
     Center aligned
  \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image]